Fullwidth for multipage table of contents ToC
A table of content in a layout with a large margin should use the full width of the page.  How can the full table of contents, which runs for more than one page, be typeset in full width? This and similar problems are often posed on SO and in the past the fullwidth package was often used.
Snce 2020 the geometry package includes options to set a new geometry and restore a previous one easily.
For cases where a page or even a number of pages should use a different layout, e.g. a ToC to use the full width of the page, geometry is now the preferred   solution. fullwidth serves cases, where only a part of a page is fullwidth (besides some special cases, as I was warned in a comment by @cabohah).
The MWE produces
first a block in the in the text column to demonstrate the layout with a wide margin,
then a ToC where the first page is full width but the second is in the main column,
and then more text to populate the ToC.
What must be changed to continue the ToC full width?
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=10mm,right=20mm,textwidth=100mm,marginparwidth=60mm,includeall}


\usepackage{fullwidth}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \begin{fullwidth}[width=160mm,twosidemode]
        \tableofcontents
    \end{fullwidth}

    \blinddocument
    \blinddocument
    \blinddocument
    \blinddocument
    \blinddocument
    \blinddocument
    
\end{document}


If you want to change the margins for the ToC, see \newgeometry (and \restoregeometry) in the geometry user manual.

I will follow the suggestion and will use the  geometry package for this case. In which cases is it advisable to use fullwidht then? For short material  (i.e. less than a page)? And use geometry for material spanning multiple pages? - is this conclusion correct?

Usually. But there could be cases with reasons to break the rule or where completely other solutions would even be better.
